# How to create nwjs app installer for MaxOS X ? Does it require MacBook to create installer?

Tags: javascript, macos, nwjs

I have created desktop application using nwjs (node webkit). I've created installer for windows successfully.

How to create installer for MacOS X?

Answer (score 0):

The official website has all the info you need http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Package%20and%20Distribute/#mac-os-x

If you want to create distribution on different platform, you could try this library https://github.com/evshiron/nwjs-builder-phoenix

Normally if you download NW.js binaries client according to the platform you need and copy javascript source code into a folder named `package.nw`(Windows) or `app.nw` in `nwjs.app/Contents/Resources/`(MacOS), the application should work out of box.